# How do I trigger a function several components higher in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Just learning React, and I would like to add an `onClick` on the font awesome icon, and run the `markTaskAsCompleted` function. I'm having trouble because it's several components lower in the hierarchy. How would you ideally go about this? Bear in mind that I also have to pass the ID of the task in the function.

```
class TasksBase extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      tasks: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onListenForTasks();
  }

  onListenForTasks() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    this.unsubscribe = this.props.firebase
      .tasks()
      .orderBy('created', 'desc')
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.size) {
          let tasks = [];
          snapshot.forEach(doc =>
            tasks.push({ ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id }),
          );
          this.setState({
            tasks: tasks,
            loading: false
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ tasks: null, loading: false });
        }
    });
  }

  markTaskAsCompleted(){
    console.log("Completed");
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    const { tasks, loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {loading && <div>Loading ...</div>}
        {tasks ? (
          <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
        ):(
          <div>There are no tasks ...</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

}


const Tasks = withFirebase(TasksBase);

const TaskList = ({ tasks }) => (
  <ul className="tasks">
    {tasks.map( task => (
      <Task key={task.uid} task={task} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const Task = ({ task }) => (
  (!task.completed && !task.obsolete && !task.waitingForDependencies) &&
  <li className="task">
    <strong>{task.userId}</strong> {task.name}
    <div className="icons">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="check-circle"/>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="times-circle" />
    </div>
  </li>
);

const condition = authUser => !!authUser;

export default compose(
  withEmailVerification,
  withAuthorization(condition),
)(Tasks);
```

Comment: There should be no problem writing `<FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => this.markTaskAsCompleted(task.userId)}`

Comment: I get "Cannot read property 'markTaskAsCompleted' of undefined", also when I bind `this` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your class function in the constructor:

```
this.markTaskAsCompleted = this.markTaskAsCompleted.bind(this);
```

Pass the function into the child component with props:

```
<TaskList tasks={tasks} handleMarkCompleted={this.markTaskAsCompleted} />
```

Pass the function again to child component, this is prop drilling and is not the latest greatest approach but it works:

```
const TaskList = ({ tasks, handleMarkCompleted }) => (
  <ul className="tasks">
    {tasks.map( task => (
      <Task key={task.uid} task={task} handleMarkCompleted={handleMarkCompleted} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

Trigger the function with `onClick`:

```
inside <Task>...
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="check-circle" onClick={() => handleMarkCompleted(task.uid)} />
```

If passing data into the function (ex. `task.uid`) make it a param in the function definition as well so you can use it:

```
markTaskAsCompleted(id){
    console.log("Completed", id);
}
```

Comment: I would just pass in the id to the function. `onClick={() => handleMarkCompleted(task.uid)`. The function will pick it up if you make it a param in the definition. I will update the snippet now.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to pass it down the tree as

> markTaskAsCompleted={this.props.markTaskAsCompleted}

and make sure that the function is bound to the parent in the constructor.

u can use refs or document.getElementById to get the ID.

Comment: Can you expand on that answer? Passing down the first level works fine, but then I get "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined".

Comment: you will need to use that in every component that is above up until the component u want to connect this action to. It is undefined because its either not being passed down through the right children, or one of the connecting children is missing the connection to that prop so it will throw off the whole flow.